# Preserving system APK UID across Android image builds

Tags: android, android-source

Is there a reliable way to specify the UID that Android assigns to the APK during the AOSP builds?

If there is a system APK that is built into and Android image, we observe that sometimes the UID associated with that APK ends up different between consecutive image builds. There seems to be little information that explains how exactly are the UIDs assigned.

The reason we'd like to preserve the UID, for at least one of the applications, is because an application needs to write to an internal file system areas, and if the UID changes between builds, then after a newer image is installed on a device, the files written by the older application are no longer accessible (the permissions to these files are 0600).

We now know that there is a "sharedUserId" Manifest statement that we can probably use for this, but since the application is already in the field, it's too late to apply that, plus that attribute has been deprecated in 29.

Comment: The uid will not be changed after upgrading the images. But if you do the factory reset, the uid may be changed.